# Python centOS no output

Tags: python, centos, output

I recently started learning Python, like 5 days ago and my problem is, when I try to run script from the vps, nothing happens. The script is located in the /root directory and I tried to chmod it. The file calls "alfa.py" and yes, i included a shebang line(or however you call that)

I tried to

```
chmod +x alfa.py
```

Still no output! This is the script (yeah.. very strange.. was just bored)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time
import urllib2
import socket
import sys
import random
import os
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def cls():
    os.system("clear")

def choices():
    print "1.IDgen\n"
    print "2.socks\n"
    print "3.XatBot (Not working)\n"
    print "4.Calculator (not working)\n"
    print "5.XatRaid(not working) \n"
    print "6.Exit\n"
    choicechoice = int(raw_input("What do you want(The number)\n"))
        if choicechoice = 6:
            exit()
        elif choicechoice = 5:
            print "Not working yet...\n"
            cls()
            choices()
        elif choicechoice = 4:
            print "Not working yet..\n"
            cls()
            choices()
        elif choicechoice = 3:
            print "Will be done soon...\n"
            cls()
            choiches()
        elif choicechoice = 1:
            cls()
            idgen()
        elif choicechoice = 2:
            print "Almost done\n"
            cls()
            time.sleep(2)
            choices()

def main():
    print "Welcome to the main menu!\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Before we start the program, we will ask you a couple of questions\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    cls()
    name = raw_input("What is your name?\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    age = int(raw_input("How old are you?\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    country = raw_input("In what country do you live?\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Thanks for the info!\n"
    time.sleep(2)
    cls()
    valid = raw_input("Is this info valid? Answer with y or n\n")
        if valid == "y"
            print "Thanks for submitting your real info!\n"
            cls()
            print "Soo, your real name is {} and you live in {} and your real age is {} ? Nice!\n".format(name, country, age)
            choices()
        else:
            exit()

def idgen():
    id = urllib2.urlopen("http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/auser3.php").read()
    if "&UserId" in id:
        file = open("idss.txt","w")
        file.write(id+"\n")
        file.close()
        print "ID generated!\n"
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print "Not an id... um??\n"
        time.sleep(2)
    choices()

main()
```

When I do `python alfa.py` Nothing happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code:

Use `==` to test for equality.

all if statement must end in `:`

`choiches()` is not the same as `choices()`

All opening `(` must have a closing `)` `int(raw_input("How old are you?\n")`  <- missing `)`

This is your code with correct syntax, go to the directory it is in and run it with `python alfa.py` :

```
import time
import urllib2
import socket
import sys
import random
import os
from time import sleep
from random import randint


def cls():
    os.system("clear")


def choices():
    print "1.IDgen\n"
    print "2.socks\n"
    print "3.XatBot (Not working)\n"
    print "4.Calculator (not working)\n"
    print "5.XatRaid(not working) \n"
    print "6.Exit\n"
    choicechoice = int(raw_input("What do you want(The number)\n"))
    if choicechoice == 6: # use `==` not =
        exit()
    elif choicechoice == 5:
        print "Not working yet...\n"
        cls()
        choices()
    elif choicechoice == 4:
        print "Not working yet..\n"
        cls()
        choices()
    elif choicechoice == 3: 
        print "Will be done soon...\n"
        cls()
        choices() # choices not  choiches()
    elif choicechoice == 1:
        cls()
        idgen()
    elif choicechoice == 2:
        print "Almost done\n"
        cls()
        time.sleep(2)
        choices()


def main():
    print "Welcome to the main menu!\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Before we start the program, we will ask you a couple of questions\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    cls()
    name = raw_input("What is your name?\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    age = int(raw_input("How old are you?\n")) # missing a closing paren
    time.sleep(2)
    country = raw_input("In what country do you live?\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Thanks for the info!\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    cls()
    valid = raw_input("Is this info valid? Answer with y or n\n")
    if valid == "y":
        print "Thanks for submitting your real info!\n"
        cls()
        print "Soo, your real name is {} and you live in {} and your real age is {} ? Nice!\n".format(name, country, age)
        choices()
    else:
        exit()


def idgen():
    id = urllib2.urlopen("http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/auser3.php").read()
    if "&UserId" in id:
        file = open("idss.txt", "w")
        file.write(id + "\n")
        file.close()
        print "ID generated!\n"
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print "Not an id... um??\n"
        time.sleep(2)
    choices()


main()
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the syntax errors but this still doesnt fix my problem... I still get no output... http://i62.tinypic.com/ampqgj.jpg

Comment: have you actually tried running it from the directory it is in using python `alfa.py`?

Comment: In my python version my print needs brackets to work. Like this: `print("Your text")`.

Comment: @D-Inventor, the default python on centos is not python 3

Comment: what happens when you just type `python`?

Comment: and you get no output at all if you `cd` to `root` and run the script?